# CSS Transition Rests as mouse moves on a rotated shape

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have been trying to fix this issue I cannot find any answers previously that match my problem and if I have then I do not understand how to get this to work.

https://jsfiddle.net/z24qehew/

```css
.diamond-container:hover, .diamond-container:active {
    -webkit-animation: all 5s linear infinite;
    -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;

    }

    @-webkit-keyframes all
    {

    0%   {-webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: rotateY(720deg);}

     }

     .tile-link {
     font-size: 20px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     float:left;
     position: absolute;
     top: 47px;
     left: 11px;
     text-align: center;
     width: 200px;
      }
 
     .diamond-container:hover > .diamond{
     background: rgba(250, 255, 0, 1);
     -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
     transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
      }

    .diamond-container:hover > .tile-link a{
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
     }

    .diamond-container {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    padding: 10px;
     }



     .diamond {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 5px solid rgba(250, 255, 0, 1);
    font: normal 100%/normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    -o-text-overflow: clip;
    text-overflow: clip;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    transform-origin: bottom center;
     }
```

```html
                <div class="diamond-container">
                    <div class="diamond">
                    </div>
                    <div class="tile-link">
                        <a href="#" class="yellow tile-link">Link</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

when you run the example you can see that the diamond resets on any slight movement and thats because the shape is basically flat at a specific point.

I think it might be something to do with the width of the container but as soon as you modify the container then the diamond is off centre on rotation.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the element triggering the animation on hover is the same element that is animating, so a new hover event happens when then mouse moves. Instead apply the animation to a child element when the parent is hovered.

```
.diamond-container:hover .diamond {
    animation: rotateY 5s ease-in-out;
}
```

The above will only make your diamond shape spin. To get it to work totally it's best to simplify the markup first. I'd recommend using a container and a single `<a>` with a `:before` psuedo-element to achieve the diamond.

Took some liberties here to reduce the code but it's working: https://jsfiddle.net/z6dqd492/

Hope this helps!